# REST api 500 (Internal Server Error) error for following a site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest

Im currently using this code to follow a site :

```
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(shptService.appWebUrl);

            var siteUrl = "https://domain.com/site1";
            executor.executeAsync({
                url: shptService.appWebUrl +"/_api/social.following/follow",
                method:"POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "actor": {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "type": "SP.Social.SocialActorInfo"
                        },
                        "ActorType": 2,
                        "ContentUri": siteUrl,
                        "Id": null
                    }
                }),
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": fDigest
                },
                success: function (responseData) {
                    stringData = JSON.stringify(responseData);
                    jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringData);
                    var statusMessage = {
                        0: 'The user has started following the site. ',
                        1: 'The user is already following the site. ',
                        2: 'An internal limit was reached. ',
                        3: 'An internal error occurred. '
                    } alert(statusMessage[jsonObject.d.Follow] + 'Status code=' +jsonObject.d.Follow);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

but i'm unfortunately having this error:

```
 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

with this message:

```
"The operation failed because an internal error occurred. Internal type name: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContentException. Internal error code: 11."
```

can anyBody help me solve this ?

Comment: Remove "X-RequestDigest": fDigest header value. executor Object automatically getthe digest value.

Comment: Still having the current Error.! :(

Comment: Well, lets try different options. use hostwebUrl in place of appweburl in place of shptService.appWebUrl +"/_api/social.following/follow". Make sure you are getting the correct values into appWebUrl and hostWebUrl  values. But use appWeburl to create RequestExecutor Object

Comment: a new error occured    " Invalid field or parameter requestInfo.url."  and yeah im pretty sure im getting those right values in appweburl and hostweburl